# Can I copy and paste all keyframed parameters (settings and effects) from one layer to another in Adobe After Effects CS6 within a single composition?

Tags: after-effects, adobe, cs6

As the question title says. Is there a shortcut, or some way to do this?
Single composition suffices.

The only thing I found is to copy all effects, by selecting a layer → effects panel → CTRL + A to select all effects → CTRL + C to copy → Go to other layer → effects panel → CTRL + V to paste the effects.

The aforementioned process copies all effects and their keyframes, but not the individual settings. The settings of each effect is the default. That being said, I am surprised to see that they are actually keyframed.

Also, it doesn't copy other keyframed parameters (non-'effects'), such as Position, or Opacity.

Is there a way to copy all keyframed parameters exactly from one layer to another?

I'm working with Adobe After Effects CS6. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the sequence window you can hit <kbd>uu</kbd> (that's double tapping the u key), to show all **modified properties**. Then copy all the keyframes *and* values (drag the cursor over the whole timeline area, including the I-beams for non-animating properties (the ones that are highlighted in blue) and copy.

[image]

If you want to copy properties that are default for one layer on to another you could use <kbd>~</kbd> instead of <kbd>uu</kbd>, that will show **all properties** of the layer.

Note that there are some effects and properties that you can't copy, they're usually things that have a custom value, like the source layer for effects that use other layers, e.g. compound blur.